# lint strict violation using (this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I cant seem to figure out how to pass 'this' element to squelch a jslint error. Here is my code:

```
function incrementFilter(event, selectedValue) {

"use strict";

$(this).html(selectedValue);

//set the next button to a var
var current = $(event.currentTarget);
var parent = $(current).parents().eq(1); // grandfather //div
var nextParent = $(parent).next().first(); // next div
var enableElem = $(nextParent).find('button');

//remove disable attr
enableElem.removeAttr("disabled");
}

//enable successive button, on each former button click
$(".irFilter .filterChosen").on("customEvent", incrementFilter);

//  apply text to dropdown after selected
$(".irFilter").on("click", "ul li", function () {

    //grab link text
    selectedValue = $(this).text();
    var thisIrFilterDiv = $(this).parents('.irFilter');
    thisFilterChosenSpan = $(thisIrFilterDiv).find('.filterChosen');

    //apply text
    thisFilterChosenSpan.trigger("customEvent", [selectedValue]);
});
```

I would like to pass the span tag as a param next to where you see the customEvent being triggered, but I cant seem to figure out how to pass it so that I dont have to use 'this' in the function.  I tried to pass it inside a JSON object and unpack it on the otherside by renaming the paramaters and looping it like this

```
function incrementFilter(event, params) {

"use strict";

var span, selectedValue;

$.each(params, function (i, item) {

    if (i === '1') {

        selectedValue = item;

    } else if (i === '2') {

        span = item;

    }
})

$(span).html(selectedValue);

//set the next button to a var
var current = $(event.currentTarget);
var parent = $(current).parents().eq(1); // grandfather //div
var nextParent = $(parent).next().first(); // next div
var enableElem = $(nextParent).find('button');

//remove disable attr
enableElem.removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

which didn't work either since I wasn't able to figure out how to use the span at that point.

whats the proper way to eliminate usage of "this" so i can pass lint?

Comment: Could you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is by adding a comment bypassing JSLint:

```
function incrementFilter(event, selectedValue) {

  "use strict";
  /* jshint validthis:true */
  $(this).html(selectedValue);
```

JSLint is trying to warn you that `this` may be `undefined` at that point.  [There's some discussion on a related project](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/621) about removing it altogether, so you should be safe ignoring this error.

(If you don't want to scatter these comments across your code, you can add `"validthis": true` to your `.jshintrc` file.  http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#validthis)

As a side note, I recommend using JSHint over JSLint (especially if you're a beginner), as Hint tries to catch errors, while Lint finds issue with your coding style as well.

Comment: +1 For the info, but OP seems to be using JSLint, although I would just recommend to switch to JSHint...

Comment: @elclanrs Fixed up the answer, and thanks for the +1